# Shell Script to Count number of Fields in a pipe(|) seperated or Ctrl-A(^A) Delimited File

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Can anyone please tell me how to count number of fields in a Pipe Separated File or Ctrl-A Separated File using shell script...

Here is my sample file:

```
1|A|3
2|B|4
3|C|5
```

I tried the below code, but it was giving '1' as output:

```
awk -F\| '{print NF; exit}' /home/user/Sruthi/Sample.txt
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: It returns `3` to me. What if you use `-F"|"`?

Comment: `awk -F '|' '{print NF;exit}' Sample.txt` using this it is giving me `3` as output

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '\^A' '{print NF;exit}' /home/user/Sruthi/Sample.txt
```